# Groovy get a list from a single object

Tags: grails, collections, groovy

I'm newbie to Groovy and I have a very simple question.

I know how to add a single element to an existing list in Java, but I guess there is a quicker way to do it in Groovy, but I don't know how ...

Supposing that I have a domain object Obj1, that takes as parameter in constructor a list of Obj2 type:

```
def obj2 = <getObj2Instance in any way>
def obj1 = new Obj1(list: obj2)
```

I'd like to know if this is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
def obj1 = new Obj1([obj2])
```

A list can be made with `[]`. For instance `[1]` will make a list with single element, *1* (integer).

Answer (score 0):

//Obj2 is a domain

def obj2List = new ArrayList< Obj2 > ()

obj2List.add(new Obj2())//add element to list like this

def obj1=new Obj1(obj2List)//obj1 takes as parameter in constructor a list      of      Obj2 type

I hope this will help u...
Try and place ur comment..
I am also new to Groovy

Comment: this is just a complicated way of writing `[obj2]`, which is the accepted answer.

Comment: This answer helped me understand what was happening in Opal's answer